# AWS EC2 can't find my .pem file with my given path

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am following this guide (https://alexioannides.com/2016/08/18/building-a-data-science-platform-for-rd-part-2-deploying-spark-on-aws-using-flintrock/) to deploy Apache Spark on an AWS EC2 instance. The error I get is the following: [aws can't find my .pem file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4yUu.png). I have my spark_cluster.pem file at /Users/myname/.ssh/spark_cluster.pem but I have tried setting this path in my [configure.yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muMmS.png) with no success. It can't find my file unless I am in the .ssh directory. The only way I can run "flintrock login my-cluster-name" to login into the AMI is by changing directories into the .ssh folder and executing the command there (with the path set to "./spark_cluster").

Thank you very much for anything that could be helpful!

Comment: Try changing the path to ~/.ssh/spark_cluster.pem

Comment: You should provide the full path to the identity-file. Something like e.g `identity-file: /Users/myname/.ssh/spark_cluster.pem`

Comment: Thank you for your responses, but I have tried both of those paths and it just says that file cannot be found.